# What is the difference between a MeSH concept and a MeSH descriptor

Tags: ontology, literature, nomenclature

Medical Subject Headings (MeSH) is a very comprehensive vocabulary to index the biomedical literature on Medline or PubMed (which is the major Biomedical literature database). MeSH is arranged into Descriptor > Concept > term hierarchy, but I still do not understand the difference between a MeSH descriptor and a MeSH concept.

For example, for Knee

- MeSH descriptor is [D007717](https://meshb.nlm.nih.gov/record/ui?ui=D007717)
- MeSH concept is [M0012066](https://meshb.nlm.nih.gov/record/ui?ui=D007717) (Under the concepts section in the link)

Even after reading the description [here](https://www.nlm.nih.gov/mesh/concept_structure.html) and [here](https://www.nlm.nih.gov/mesh/xmlmesh.html), I am still not sure about the purpose of MeSH concept and MeSH descriptor.

Could anyone please shed some light on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MeSH is organized into `Descriptor > Concept > Term hierarchy`, where all the synonymous `<term>`'s are grouped together under a `<concept>`. For example, consider the MeSH terms,

1. Blood-Brain Barrier
2. Hemato-Encephalic Barrier
3. Brain-Blood Barrier

All these terms are group under the umbrella concept of "[Blood-brain barrier](https://meshb.nlm.nih.gov/record/ui?ui=D001812)".